# C - Trying to find a char[] in a charArray[n][] and record the value of n

Tags: c, arrays, string, compare, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to loop through fooArray search each entry for foo and increment fooCount in the appropriate entry. As it stands the string: H A P Y \0 is successfully input into both foo and fooArray[2] but I can't get fooArray[2] == foo to evaluate to true.

Should I be using string.h and strcmp or strstr for this?
Why doesn't fooArray[2] == foo to evaluate to true?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){

    char foo[5] = "HAPY";
    static char fooArray[4][5] = {"abc", "123", "HAPY", "some"};
    int fooCount[4] = {0};
    int n;

    printf("size of fooArray: %d\n", ( sizeof(fooArray) / sizeof(fooArray[0])));

    for (n = 0; n < sizeof(fooArray) / sizeof(fooArray[0]); n++) {
        if (fooArray[n] == foo) {
            fooCount[n]++;
            break;
        }
    }

    for (n = 0; n < sizeof(fooArray) / sizeof(fooArray[0]); n++) 
        printf(" fooArray[%d] = %s \n", n, fooArray[n]);

    for (n = 0; n < sizeof(fooCount) / sizeof(fooCount[0]); n++) 
        printf(" fooCount[%d] = %d \n", n, fooCount[n]);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: for a very complete overview of strings in C, see `man string` on a linux terminal or this: http://linux.die.net/man/3/string (to relieve you of having to google 'man string' :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

comparison between strings is to be done by `strcmp`  not just compare by `==`

Comment: Thanks, 
    strcmp (fooArray[n], foo) == 0
works. Since strcmp can return equal to, greater than, and less than values is it possible that two unlike strings will evaluate to 0 if the sum of their chars is equal?

Comment: Not possible, the strcmp() does no checksum. I compares character by character, and as soon as two corresponding characters differ, it can't return zero.

Answer (score 1):

As Raghu says, you need to use strcmp in your first for loop:

```
for (n = 0; n < sizeof(fooArray) / sizeof(fooArray[0]); n++) {
    if (!strcmp(fooArray[n], foo)) { /* if equal then strcmp() will return zero */
        fooCount[n]++;
        break;
    }
}
```